# How to get the sum under different conditions in one query?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, informix

How to do the following in one query :

If i have two queries like that

```
SELECT SUM(value +sal) AS sump
FROM loans 
WHERE active_flag = 1
```

---

```
SELECT SUM(value +sal) AS sumn
FROM loans 
WHERE active_flag = 2
```

---

I want to get `sump` and `sumn` in the same query

Comment: What is the primary key for the loans table?

Comment: @MDiesel - Why is that relevant?

Comment: I was just going to write two subqueries, one for each calculation, and join back to the main query on the primary key.

Comment: @MDiesel That's severely unnecessary

Comment: @Kermit:Could i do the same query but with `COUNT` instead of `SUM`

Comment: @just_name I don't see why not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN active_flag = 1 THEN value + sal 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS sump,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN active_flag = 2 THEN value + sal 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS sumn 
FROM   loans 
WHERE  active_flag IN ( 1, 2 )
```